# Rails 4 + Serialization: Disable ActiveModel::Serializer for view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, serialization, active-model-serializers

I have an API with a search function that returns a list of `client` objects.   Normally I like to use my `client` serializer to control which attributes are returned.  However, when searching, I'd like to require fewer `attributes` so that the search can be completed more quickly.

**My controller**

```
def index
  @clients = Client.order("created_at ASC")

    if params[:search].present?
      @clients = Client.select('name', 'id').where("(name like ?) OR (name like ?)", "%#{params[:search]}%", "%#{params[:search].titleize}%")
    end

    paginate json: @clients, serializer: nil, per_page: 25
end
```

`serializer: nil` has no effect because my logs show each returned `client` grabbing all it's associations that I don't need and still shows `active_model_serializers` throughout the log.

**log**

```
Client Load (0.8ms)  SELECT  "clients"."name", "clients"."id" FROM "clients" WHERE ((name like '%ta%') OR (name like '%Ta%')) LIMIT 25 OFFSET 0
# I don't need any of this (below)
[active_model_serializers]   CheckIn Load (1.3ms)  SELECT "check_ins".* FROM "check_ins" WHERE "check_ins"."client_id" = $1  ORDER BY created_at ASC  [["client_id", 1363]]
[active_model_serializers]   Payment Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "payments".* FROM "payments" WHERE "payments"."client_id" = $1  [["client_id", 1363]]
[active_model_serializers]   Purchase Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "purchases".* FROM "purchases" WHERE "purchases"."client_id" = $1  [["client_id", 1363]]
[active_model_serializers]   Program Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "programs".* FROM "programs" WHERE "programs"."client_id" = $1  [["client_id", 1363]]
```

**What can I do to prevent the additional attributes from being loaded?**

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve my problem by changing the following line:

```
paginate json: @clients, serializer: nil, per_page: 25
```

to:

```
paginate json: @clients, adapter: false, per_page: 25
```